# Why would I get slower uploads on a Windows machine than my Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, networking, upload, throughput

I have a proprietary app, written in Java, that uploads files to a server via multiple HTTPS POST requests. There's a Mac version and a Windows version.

On the Mac, we easily get 3-5mbps upload speeds. Nice!

On Windows machines we've tried with a comparable processor speed & RAM, the upload will very often cap out at 800kbps. (Though on my Windows 7 machine, it won't do this.)

A lot of people are still using Windows XP. Could that be an issue? Is there anything else we should keep in mind?

Comment: Are you saying that on your Windows 7 machine. You get full speed? (4.5Mbps)

Comment: Are the NICs the same?

Answer (score 1):

You should check your network settings for your chosen network device. One thing in windows that can cause a major difference in speed is your link speed & duplex, for wired connections; if you have this set to something lower than what your network supports, you can have reduced speeds.

If this is set to Auto Negotiate, if might be automatically picking a lower speed because your network isn't specifying its speed or duplex.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have other processes running in the background of windows machine which is sucking up the bandwidth? Does both machine have the same version of JRE? Is there any programming differences between the Mac version and PC version? Is it possible that the Mac version are more optimized?